# Mapping object as identity column in entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

It is possible map object as identity column with value generated typeof int ?
I tried like this but this no help. i've got error

Identity value generation cannot be used for the property 'Id' on entity type 'Article' because the property type is 'ArticleId'. Identity value generation can only be used with signed integer properties.

```cs
    public class ArticleId
    {
        public int Value { get; private set; }

        public ArticleId(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    public class Article 
    {

        public ArticleId Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
     
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var converter = new ValueConverter<ArticleId, int>(
                                    v => v.Value,
                                    v => new ArticleId(v)
        );

       modelBuilder
       .Entity<Article>()
       .Property(p => p.Id)     
       .HasConversion(converter)
       .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
       .UseIdentityColumn();

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Consider this discussion, might be related. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11597

Comment: The bounty wasn't necessary. EF now [supports it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#value-objects-as-keys) - sort of.

Comment: @GertArnold Hmm, if by "now" you mean the upcoming EFC 7.0 (November this year)? Until then, the "little" note from the link still applies *"Currently key properties with conversions cannot use generated key values. Vote for GitHub issue #11597 to have this limitation removed."*

Comment: @Ivan Yeah, "sort of" was a vague disclaimer for all issues this feature suffers from. Even when identity will be supported I'm afraid querying will remain cumbersome in some cases. To me, the text in the docs clearly indicates they're wary of supporting it and won't go out of their way to make it a smooth developer experience.

Comment: When did you get this error? While updating database? Or, while trying to create migration?

Comment: Thank you everybody to back to this topic after 2 years, i founded some solutions maybe currently I am not using int but i achieved what i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this Attribute for the `Id` property in the `Article` class:

```
public class Article
{
    [Column(TypeName = "int IDENTITY(1,1)")]
    public ArticleId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The migration part will be like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Articles",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int IDENTITY(1,1)", nullable: false),
            Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Articles", x => x.Id);
        });
}
```

And the table in the database is like this:
[image: database]

Comment: You clearly didn't test this: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'Article' requires a primary key to be defined. ". And if you configure `Id` as key: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Article.Id' is of type 'ArticleId' which is not supported by the current database provider. " Please test code before posting. How would EF spontaneously create an `ArticleId` from an int?

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot use a reference type as a primary key, you'll have to rearchitecture to not have a reference type as a key, however You can make a composite key, so if you take your model and change it to have a primitive type primary key.

Perhaps when squinting at your Article Id, you can allow it doesn't really do anything, so just change it to int ArticleId and it will be key by convention being  either called Id og Id

See details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

This has been [addressed](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11597) in EF Core 7. As of writing you can upgrade to the latest release candidate, and the following will work:

```
public readonly record struct CustomerId(int Value);

public class Cutomer
{ 
    public CustomerId Id { get; }

    //......
}

var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>();

entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

entity.Property(e => e.Id)
    .HasConversion(
       id => id.Value, 
       intValue => new CustomerId(intValue));
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Comment: ye, i tracked this topic :)